# How to make virtual interface ping to a host in the network

Tags: networking, ethernet, ip

I created a virtual interface as indicated in this [Unix.SE post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152331/how-can-i-create-a-virtual-ethernet-interface-on-a-machine-without-a-physical-ad). I.e.

```
sudo modprobe dummy
sudo ip link set name eth10 dev dummy0
sudo ifconfig eth10 up
sudo ifconfig eth10 192.168.1.150
```

I want to send a ping to a host in my network (`ping 192.168.1.133`), but it does not work.

I tried to add

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth10.forwarding=1
```

But that does not work either.

What should I do to make the ping work?

Answer (score 1):

You make mistake

not

```
sudo ifconfig eth10 192.168.1.150
```

you must add network mask

```
sudo ifconfig eth10 192.168.1.150 netmask 255.255.255.0
```